# Adding comments to xml documents

Tags: python, xml

Code:

```
from lxml import etree

# Create the network XML file tree
root = etree.Element('network')
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)

# Create the nodes data
name = etree.Element('nodes')
root.append(name)
element = etree.SubElement(name, 'node')
element.set('id', '1')

# Create the links data
name = etree.Element('links')
root.append(name)
element = etree.SubElement(name, 'link')
element.set('id', '2')

# Print document to screen
print etree.tostring(root, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<network>
  <nodes>
    <node id="1"/>
  </nodes>
  <links>
    <link id="2"/>
  </links>
</network>
```

The code above produces this output. However, apart from the declaration which is used as arguments in the tostring() method and printed at the top of the document. I am yet to figure out how to make comments visible if you want them say midway in the document. I have seen earlier posts like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474754/how-to-keep-comments-while-parsing-xml-using-python-elementtree), but it didn't answer my question.  Can someone help me with how I can do this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <network>
      <nodes>
        <node id="1"/>
      </nodes>

         <!-- ==============Some Comment============================= -->
    
      <links>
        <link id="2"/>
      </links>
    </network>
```

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title. Also, `xlmx` isn't a thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To insert a comment you can do this, after your code:

```
comment = etree.Comment(' === Some Comment === ')
root.insert(1, comment)  # 1 is the index where comment is inserted
```

If you want to add spaces, for instance in the tail of the `nodes` element, [that may mess with prettyprint](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-doesn-t-the-pretty-print-option-reformat-my-xml-output), because once there is text in tails it won't know where to add whitespace safely. I suppose you could use the same technique as `indent`, from [ElementLib](http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm).